# VirtueMart - 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: azure, joomla, proxy, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 3.3 and VirtueMart 3.0 on a Windows Azure Website. When I go to extension manager and install VirtueMart, I get this error:

502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

I am using ClearDB. I have application logging turned on, however, I see no logs in my FTP.

I see that all the files for VirtueMart exist in my FTP and the database appears to have all tables. It looks like a part registering the VirtueMart module with PHP fails. Does Joomla have a log that I can turn on?